# How to select the parent elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, parent

I am trying to make a sidebar that stores the last click link into the local storage and still opens the collapse links after the page reloads.

```
$(".clickedLink").parent().parent().css('background-color', 'green');
```

Could someone help me how to select elements?

Example: If I click the "PHP Advanced" link it will select the #5 & #6, also the #1 & #2. But not selecting the #3 & #4...

```
<a class="nav-link" aria-expanded="false">Programming</a> __#1__
<div class="collapse"> __#2__
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="nav-link" aria-expanded="false">HTML</a> __#3__
            <div class="collapse"> __#4__
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../html/html-basic.php" class="nav-link">HTML Basic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../html/html-advanced.php" class="nav-link">HTML Advanced</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../html/html-examples.php" class="nav-link">HTML Examples</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="nav-link" aria-expanded="false">PHP</a> __#5__
            <div class="collapse"> __#6__
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../php/php-basic.php" class="nav-link">PHP Basic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../php/php-advanced.php" class="nav-link clickedLink">PHP Advanced</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../php/php-examples.php" class="nav-link">PHP Examples</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me out

Comment: You can do `.closest("parent_class")` or `.parents("parent_class")`

Comment: __#3__ and __#4__ are not parents for PHP Advanced link. __#5__ as well, even though __#5__ doesnt have any child elements

Comment: Assign an ID for #3 and #5, It would be simpler

Comment: #1 is not the parent of your clicked element, I guess you need to revise your question a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. call `parents('.collapse')` to get all parents with given class. Then call `prev()` to get the links.

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  var parents = $(this).parents('.collapse');
  parents.css('border-top', '1px solid red');
  parents.prev().css('border-top', '1px solid blue');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-link" aria-expanded="false">Programming</a> __#1__
<div class="collapse"> __#2__
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="nav-link" aria-expanded="false">HTML</a> __#3__
            <div class="collapse"> __#4__
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../html/html-basic.php" class="nav-link">HTML Basic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../html/html-advanced.php" class="nav-link">HTML Advanced</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../html/html-examples.php" class="nav-link">HTML Examples</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="nav-link" aria-expanded="false">PHP</a> __#5__
            <div class="collapse"> __#6__
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../php/php-basic.php" class="nav-link">PHP Basic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../php/php-advanced.php" class="nav-link clickedLink">PHP Advanced</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../php/php-examples.php" class="nav-link">PHP Examples</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```